# Parse.com - Signup View Additional Field - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, syntax-error, field

I need to have an additional field in the sign up screen, I have looked up the code and this is what I see

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   // self.signUpViewController.additionalField; setPlaceholder ("Phone Number")
    PFSignUpController.fields = (PFSignUpFields.UsernameAndPassword
        | PFSignUpFields.SignUpButton
        | PFSignUpFields.Email
        | PFSignUpFields.Additional
        | PFSignUpFields.DismissButton)


}
```

However, I get an error saying: "Use of unresolved identifier 'PFSignUpViewController'" I don't know why I am getting this because the code was obtained from the Parse.com website itself.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Is it suppose to be `PFSignUpViewController.fields` instead of `PFSignUpController.fields`?

Comment: PFSignUpViewController.fields does not have a member named fields error @kylecman

Comment: @ArafatQureshi `PFSignUpViewController` does have a property named fields. Check the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFSignUpViewController.html#//api/name/fields). So fields should be configured on an instance of PFSignupViewController, so subclass it, instantiate it, and then set the fields value. Or, if you don't need to subclass it, from a PFLoginViewController use`self.signupViewController.fields` to configure it.